# Excel using index & match instead of vlookup

Tags: excel

My goal is to get student grades with INDEX & MATCH from G column to B column. I can do it with VLOOKUP function but could someone help me to get them with INDEX & MATCH?

[image: Here is my data]

My goal output:

[image]

Comment: Man, this is really basic stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste this in B2 and drag:

> =INDICE($F$2:$G$5;CONFRONTA(A2;$F$2:$F$5;0);2)

Translation:

> =INDEX($F$2:$G$5,MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$5;0),2)